# How to compare two string urls in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Can someone suggest how to compare two urls in bash. I am getting false for below values.

```
var1=https://sample.myweb.net/templateuri/abc?resource
var2=https://sample.myweb.net/templateuri/abc?resource
```

Getting true for below condition.

```
if [[ "$var1" != "$var2" ]]; then
  echo 'var1 and var2 not same'
fi
```

Can you please help to how go inside condition if not same only.

Comment: Use single quotes: `var1='...'`

Comment: `I am getting false for below values` [I'm not, repl link](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/Bash-1)

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working as assignment with quotes.

```
actVal="$var1"  expVal="$var2"   if [[ "$actVal" != "$expVal" ]]; then
```